# Facebook sdk is not a dylib error after update update Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I got some errors with facebook sdk after update Xcode 7 when i tried to build the project like the code below.

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/manjarb/Desktop/hubbalabs/lib/FacebookSDK/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit', framework linker option at /Users/manjarb/Desktop/hubbalabs/lib/FacebookSDK/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit is not a dylib
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/manjarb/Desktop/hubbalabs/lib/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit', framework linker option at /Users/manjarb/Desktop/hubbalabs/lib/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit is not a dylib
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/manjarb/Desktop/hubbalabs/lib/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit', framework linker option at /Users/manjarb/Desktop/hubbalabs/lib/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit is not a dylib
```

[image]

How to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Add them into 'Link Binary With Libraries' under 'Build Phases'

Comment: I had this error when integrating the frameworks in an Xcode sub-project then trying to use calls in the host project.  Linking against the Facebook framework in the parent project corrected this.

Answer (score 24):

When you install Facebook SDK iOS frameworks the way Facebook advices it, you do two things:

1. - create a "Frameworks" group in XCode if it doesn't exist
   - drag used frameworks into the "Frameworks" group
     (this automagically creates an entry in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries)
2. Set the Framework search Paths to .../FacebookSDKs-iOS/

You get this "not a dylib" warning when you succeeded with 2. but did not do 1. correctly.

In my case I got this warning for the `Bolts.framework`, which I didn't use directly but is used by `FBSDKCoreKit.framework`.

Dragging `Bolts.framework` into XCode next to `FBSDKCoreKit.framework` fixed the warning.

Comment: What's the proper way to create a "Frameworks" group. I tried adding a group from the File > New dropdown menu and then dragging and dropping the frameworks, but that didn't seem to work for me. So, I used these instructions: http://docs.onemobilesdk.aol.com/ios-ad-sdk/adding-frameworks-xcode.html

Comment: @chez.mosey, another way to create the Frameworks group is to right click the top level app icon in the "folder/tree view" on the left panel of XCode. Then select "New Group". When you drag *.framework files into this group a *.framework entry is added to Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries.