# Facebook iOS SDK gives "is not a dylib" warning

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

After the last update of xcode 7.3 i am having

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied `'/Users/utkudalmaz/Developer/Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts', framework linker option at /Users/utkudalmaz/Developer/Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts is not a dylib`
```

warning. Anyone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook sdk is not a dylib error after update update Xcode 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690590/facebook-sdk-is-not-a-dylib-error-after-update-update-xcode-7)

Comment: yes possible duplicate, but this question and answer are much more clear

Answer (score 13):

I don't have the reputation to close as duplicate, so the answer is:

FBSDKCoreKit references Bolts but you probably haven't added Bolts explicitly to your Xcode project.

To remedy this, dragging Bolts.framework into Xcode next to FBSDKCoreKit.framework will fix the warning.

As seen in this older question: [Facebook sdk is not a dylib error after update update Xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690590/facebook-sdk-is-not-a-dylib-error-after-update-update-xcode-7)

Comment: Worked for me to.  Had to do a full clean (cmd-shift-k) and rebuild