# Xcode 9 _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to implement Facebook SDK into my project and I get the same issue
[Facebook sdk is not a dylib error after update update Xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690590/facebook-sdk-is-not-a-dylib-error-after-update-update-xcode-7)
Well, I have `Bolts` in my `Frameworks` Directory, also

In my `Build Settings`:
`Frameworks Search Path: ~/Documents/Frameworks/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.27.0`
(That is correct for my path)

In my `Briding-Header.h`

```
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

But, I'm still getting the same error, also, I just deleted the `Derived data`.

The error is:

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/jarvis/Documents/Frameworks/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.27.0/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit', framework linker option at /Users/jarvis/Documents/Frameworks/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.27.0/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit is not a dylib
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/jarvis/Documents/Frameworks/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.27.0/Bolts.framework/Bolts', framework linker option at /Users/jarvis/Documents/Frameworks/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.27.0/Bolts.framework/Bolts is not a dylib
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/jarvis/Documents/Frameworks/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.27.0/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit', framework linker option at /Users/jarvis/Documents/Frameworks/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.27.0/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Some one has an idea about this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the solution was weird, basically, I removed the Drag and Drop to my `Framework` group, and I added the `FBSDKCoreKit`, `FBSDKLoginKit` and `Bolt` using the general settings adding them in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`

Comment: This is what happened too me too very weird

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error and ***cleaning the project and building it again*** 4-5 times worked for me.

- Cleaning - Command + Shift + K
- Building - Command + B

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to delete these files in the project folder:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa9p2.jpg)

- pod install

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30179219)

Answer (score -1):

instead of using the method described in FB official reference, I used pods to install them and I easily got rid of this problem